# FFMPEG How to add gif water mark to mp4 video with loop,scale,overlay positionig

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, watermark

This is my code

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4  -i anim.gif -filter_complex "[1:v] loop=-1,scale=300:-1 [ol], [0:v] [ol] overlay=W-w:H-h-10" -codec:a copy -y out.mp4
```

But am unable  to put it in loop the gif according to video length

Am also trying to scale the gif width to 30% of th main video width
Gif positioing working here am able to position the gif at the bootom right corner
But i also need to scale it according to main video width

Answer (score 1):

add `-ignore_loop 0` to gif input:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i anim.gif -filter_complex "
[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=w=iw*0.3:h=ow*mdar [ol][bg];
[bg][ol] overlay=W-w:H-h-10:eof_action=pass
" -shortest -c:a copy -y out.mp4
```

use `scale2ref` for 30% scale of input video